# NLCD disappears after I reclassified it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, reclassify, nlcd

I pulled NLCD data into my project, reclassified, everything was fine.
New reclassified layer worked great, saved project, closed. Re-opened this morning, reclassified NLCD is in TOC, but is not appearing on my map. The original NLCD layer is there, working fine, but the reclassified layer is what I need.

What could be the issue?

One source suggested clearing the cache, but that did nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What happens if you pull up the reclassified NLCD outside of your project? There may be a corrupt mxd file.